# How do I run IBM Watson Tone Analysis example code?

Tags: python, ibm-watson

I am trying to run the test code for IBM Watson Tone Analysis

```py
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data-binary @{path_to_file}tone.json \
"{url}/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21
```

However, I keep getting the error:

> Warning: Couldn't read data from file
> Warning: "{pathname}tone.json", this makes an empty POST.
>
> {"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}%

Answer (score 0):

You have two different errors.

The first indicates that the path that you have specified for the `tone.json` file is incorrect.

The second indicates that you are using the wrong credentials for the url that you are attempting to hit. Ie. Either your apikey or your endpoint is incorrect.